# Is there issue with new version of node.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js

```
Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:444:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:715:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1130:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Web_coding\ReactJS\cnapp\node_modules\which\which.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
```

```
{
  "name": "cnapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^7.7.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Tried with deleting node modules folder but same.

Comment: Try giving entry point of application using main key

Comment: It works after deleting node modules and running command npm i.